# How to look at Bitmap objects in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, c#-4.0, bitmap

I am building a C# app that creates many bitmaps (System.Drawing.Image). Having the bitmaps seen in the debugger as pictures, would be of enormous help. The debugger has native support for XML files. Is there a way to see the pictures?

Comment: +1 good question, this would be awesome in apps like hawkeye.codeplex.com, http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/debuggercanva, whats this about XML files - do you have a link?

Comment: XML preview is natively supported by VS on any string. Just hover over any System.String in the debugger, you will see a magnifier icon. There you may choose the visualization types. XML is one of them.

Comment: I usually use something like `bitmap.Save(@"C:\test.bmp")` from the Immediate Window to view my bitmaps when debugging, although I know this isn't ideal when debugging a large number of bitmaps :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no debugger visualizer by default for Bitmap, so you might want to give this one a try: http://imagedebugvisualizer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is there one for later versions of Visual Studio?

Comment: For VS 2015/2017:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AleksanderBerus.DebuggerImageVisualizerPreview

Comment: The link is dead since CodePlex was shutdown.

Answer (score 14):

Another open source image and bitmap visualizer which works in Visual Studio 2019:

https://github.com/Jaex/ImageVisualizer

Screenshot from it:

[image]

Comment: Does your visualizer work with WPF images as well? The documentation on github has no hints about that.

Comment: Only GDI Image/Bitmap.

Answer (score 5):

I did it this way before I read Rachel's comment above which would have been much easier....

You could Base64 encode it - in your immediate Window:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
yourImage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
base64string = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Then copy and paste the value of base64string into your favourite base64 debugger, e.g.

https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Answer (score 2):

This program works for me in 2013 and should work from 2010 - 15
http://bytescout.com/products/developer/bitmapvisualizer/index.html

Comment: Not working for me on VS2013 Ultimate Update 2. :(
Someone left a review saying the same: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eae1b934-bff2-4a20-99ef-41e6b9a4aee4?SRC=VSIDE

Comment: update: the current version (as of October 2015) of this plugin works with VS2013 and VS2015 now. Disclosure: I work for ByteScout

Comment: I've just installed it in VS2010 and it works perfectly. If there are some limitations in Trial version I don't find them anywhere. @EugeneM could you please tell us ?

Comment: @AFract it is a free plugin!

Comment: Ok thanks :). That was also my guess but it's absolutely not clear on your company website due to the "Download free trial" button and "FREE for commercial
and non-commercial use" warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try BitMapVisualizer by ByteScout
http://bytescout.com/products/developer/bitmapvisualizer/index.html

Trial version is for free

Answer (score 0):

Another good option is [Bitmap & BitmapSource Visualizer for Visual Studio 2013](https://bitmapsourcevisualizer.codeplex.com/). It also has bonus as source code (I used it for recompiling into 4.5 framework due to problems with 3.5 in my machine).

By default it adds `Width` and `Height` information about image (in contrast of [Bytescout](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/bitmapvisualizer/index.html) plugin, which adds more info), but you can add any information through code - there just simple `String.Format` using.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are good but yet another alternative is to write your own debugger visualizer, which is supported by VS for a long time. There is a good old CodeProject article showing how to write a debugger visualizer:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24211/Graphics-Debugger-Visualizer

Using this method I had also written other visualizers before such as DataTable visualizer. Not just for Bitmap visualizer, this is up to your custom needs and you can write any visualizer.

The process is pretty easy: Write your visualizer, compile it as a DLL and drop it into your *VS\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers* folder.