# How to preview a bitmap in Rider debugging session?

Tags: bitmap, rider

I'm coming from Visual Studio. It has a feature that I quite heavily use - custom visualizers for data.

As described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246831/how-to-look-at-bitmap-objects-in-visual-studio-debugger), there is a visualizer that allows you to see bitmaps stored in `Bitmap` type variables right in the debugging session.

Is there something like this in Rider? Or do I have to use Interactive Session to save the bitmap to disk every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Rider right now, but you can track the progress here (no estimates so far):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4871

Comment: thanks, that's a bit sad, since it means I will have still jump between the two IDEs... other JetBrains products don't have it either, right?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has this feature